# How to add subsubsection in mybook.cls

Tags: sectioning, thesis, sections-paragraphs

i am using mybook.cls class for my thesis. I want to add subsubsection which should appear in table of contents as well but its not coming. Anyone found any solution to this? I have tried using paragraph but its not working.

Comment: I do not know that class (it is not in texlive)  but usually `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` would make subsubsections appear in the table of contents.

Comment: where i have to add that can you explain in detail

Comment: No sorry that is actually the  default value in the standard classes so most likely somewhere in code you have not shown it gets changed. Please always include a complete small document that shows the issue. With no information it is impossible to guess where to change unseen code.

Answer (score -1):

The memoir class sports extensive customizability, including numbering lower sectioning, *very* flexible chapter heading format (lots of fancy formats predefined, a heap of others available), and so on. I've used it for several largeish lecture notes.